# Column lookup formula in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

Below is the table and I need to populate a column based on a lookup formula.

```
**Key        P-Key    Main ID    F Key**
ID-2    BMWBMA                 User Case 1
ID-3    MERCEDES               User Case 2
ID-4    AUDI                   User Case 3
ID-5    Factory                Factory
ID-6    Godown                 Godown
```

How do I populate Main ID based on the below condition,
**Key** Value assigned to **Main ID**.
(When P-Key=F-Key)

```
**Key    P-Key       Main ID    Warehouse         F-Key**
ID-2    BMWBMA        ID-5      Factory          User Case 1
ID-3    MERCEDES      ID-5      Factory          User Case 2
ID-4    AUDI          ID-6      Godown           User Case 3
ID-5    Factory       ID-5      Factory          Factory
ID-6    Godown        ID-6      Godown           Godown
```

Comment: Does this need to be a formula or is it a viable option to use vba?

Comment: I'm looking for a simple solution using vlookup or match

Comment: Why should the top line have Main ID = ID-5? The P-Key is Factory and the F-Key is User Case 1. Those keys are not equal.

Comment: Don't go too much into the column names, I just want the logic to function so I can populate the table

Comment: Question hard to understand and you need to show effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table starts in A1, put this in C2 and copy it down:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,CHOOSE({1,2,3}, D:D, B:B, A:A), 3, FALSE)
```

This performs a "backwards" `VLOOKUP`, where we have reversed the order of the columns (and skipped column C to avoid a circular reference) using the `CHOOSE` function.

Comment: Doesn"t give what I'm looking for

Comment: Hmm, you've changed your sample data quite a bit. I don't understand how you're translating from the sample data to the desired results anymore. Why would your row with a **Key value of ID-2 have a Main ID value of ID-5? It doesn't match your condition of P-Key=F-Key. And where did `Warehouse` show up from?